# Warn user that data may be lost for custom pages

Tags: custom-field, options, validation, plugin-options

When you edit a builtin field in Wordpress like the title and don't save the cahnges, and attempt to go to another link, a warning alert box comes up stating that "changes may be lost if you navigate ...".

How can I make that same box appear for my own pages?

Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you have to make a javascript code similar to this...

```
jQuery(function ($) {

    name = $('#name').val();
    $('#name').data('old_value',name);

    window.onbeforeunload = function () {
        if ($('#name').data('old_value') !== $('#name').val())
            return 'You have unsaved changes!';
    }

});
```

here's a [demo page](http://fiddle.jshell.net/owLbs73h/4/show/)... try closing the page after changing the value of the textbox there...

Comment: Wow I didn't think it'll be that simple lol!